# Smartd how to wake disks only for scheduled scans

Tags: smartctl, smartmontools

I am using smartd to monitor my disks in Ubuntu and have it configured to run a short scan daily at 2am and a long test 3am every Saturday morning:

`/dev/sda -a -n standby -o on -S on -s (S/../.././02|L/../../6/03) -m name@mail.com`

I understand that smartd periodically polls the disks (every 30mins?) causing them to wakeup if in stand by, hence I have added the `-n standby` flag in the above config. However, this also stops the scheduled scans from running if the disk is in standby.

Is there a way to force the scheduled scans to start at the given times and wake the disks if needed, but stop the periodic polling form waking the disks ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible to do exactly what you’re asking, but it is possible to reduce the impact of the periodic polls by having them run less frequently. This is done with `smartd`’s `--interval` option; by default it’s 1800 seconds (30 minutes, as you noticed), but it can be set to much longer intervals.

On my system, `/etc/default/smartmontools` has the following line:

```
smartd_opts="--interval=10800"
```

so `smartd` runs its periodic poll every three hours. It also runs the configured checks at the times specified in `/etc/smartd.conf`.